# telnet link does not open shell extension in firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, telnet

There some strange issue on my firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 7 and Windows 10. I can't open telnet links - like "telnet://some.server.org:123".

Same links work properly on Chrome or in Firefox on Windows XP. When i click on link, Firefox suggests me to open it with Internet Shortcut Shell Extension DLL.

I think, that the command to run is "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" "C:\Windows\System32\url.dll",TelnetProtocolHandler %l - as set in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telnet\shell\open\command But nothing happens when I click "OK" or when I set "Internet Shortcut Shell Extension DLL" as default and click to a link.

Answer (score 3):

save the following text as a .reg file, and run it.
You must have putty.exe in your C:\Program Files\putty\ directory.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telnet]
@="URL:Telnet Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telnet\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telnet\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telnet\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\putty\\putty.exe\" %1"
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't the telnet command inside in Windows 7 and above by default. So, you have to enabled telnet client in Windows Features first.

Comment: Sorry, I had to specify that telnet is enabled more clearly. Chrome can open telnet link on same system.